# In Highcharts Make tooltip of a specific point always visible and dynamically i will change its point

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i have created a line chart and make tooltip visible at particular point by this code

```
$('#container').highcharts({

            chart: {
                events: {
                    load: function(){
                        var p = this.series[0].points[0];
                        this.tooltip.refresh(p);  
                    }
                }
            },


            tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },

            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
            }]
        });
```

like this [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/489j7nxm/1/)!

now i want to change the position of tooltip to next point/previous point using keyboard arrow key left and right how can in do it using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by using the `document.onkeydown` method. You have to get the key press code for the arrow keys:
37 = left
39 = right

Then you have to know what data point you are already on. I did this with a scoped variable that contains the point index we are trying to get with a starter value (`p`). I then changed the naming of the point's options to `ttPoint` and passed that to the `this.tooltip.refresh();` method.

The code to capture the key press uses `onkeydown`. This is document wide. I get the current chart options and the maximum index of the data point such that we do not try to change the tooltip location to a point that does not exist.

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var theChart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var maxP = theChart.series[0].points.length;
    console.log(p);
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            console.log('left');
            if (p == 0) {
                p = p;
            } else {
                p = p - 1;
            }
            theChart.tooltip.refresh(theChart.series[0].points[p]);
            break;
        case 38:
            console.log('up');
            break;
        case 39:
            console.log('right');
            if (p == maxP) {
                p = p;
            } else {
                p = p + 1;
            }
            theChart.tooltip.refresh(theChart.series[0].points[p]);
            break;
        case 40:
            console.log('down');
            break;
    }
};
```

I left the up/down codes in there as well if you need them to change the series you are looking at. Sample [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/489j7nxm/2/).

Comment: i have another problem with this when i am adding series dynamically in the chart so it gives me error at point so i feel that i want to declare the events.load dynamically just tell me how should i do that

Comment: ok i remove that problem and it is working properly but marker is not enabled for that point what should i do please tell me if you have any idea about it

Comment: can i use it with shared tooltip because if when i use it with the shared tooltip it not going to see anything so please tell me somthing about that thanks in advance

Comment: @FirozTennali I see no reason why you couldn't use this with a shared tooltip. Do you have a sample jsFiddle with some of your series values? I see what you mean about the point not being graphically updated.